# Task<IActionResult> is getting the wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(OperationResponse<Plan>))]
        [ProducesResponseType(400, Type = typeof(OperationResponse<Plan>))]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute]  string id)
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
            Console.WriteLine("stack is " + t);
            var plan = await _plansService.GetPlanById(id, userId);
            if (plan == null)
                return BadRequest(new OperationResponse<string>
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = "Invalid operation",
                });

            return Ok(new OperationResponse<Plan>
            {
                Record = plan,
                Message = "Plan retrieved successfully!",
                IsSuccess = true,
                OperationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
            });
        }
```

string id should be of type guid and instead I'm getting the word 'search'  instead of id which should be a guid for a particular product. How do I trace the value.... or the mapping?

[image: This is the error]

Comment: I don't think you understand how a `RouteParameter` works: If you want to pass the id as a route parameter your url would look like: `api/plans/guid` not `api/plans/search`

Comment: So there must be a mismatch on on how the routing takes place?

Comment: Can't really say, all I have to go on is your example. If that's the only `Get` request in your controller, then I suppose it's trying to route to that endpoint.

Comment: We do not know what your expected route looks like because you did not post that code. We do not know who is making the actual request and why they think their route is given correctly. But it's clear the two do not match. This question cannot be answered without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing api to

```
var response = await client.GetProtectedAsync<ProductsCollectionPagingResponse>($"{_baseUrl}/api/plans/query={query}/page={page}");
```

from

```
 var response = await client.GetProtectedAsync<ProductsCollectionPagingResponse>($"{_baseUrl}/api/plans?query={query}&page={page}");
```

Comment: In this example, which one would be `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL `/api/plans/search?query=you&page=1` has nothing that could be parsed as a GUID in it. Presumably the route prefix on the controller is `/api/plans/` so in declaring `id` as `FromRoute` in your action you have a route of `/api/plans/{id}`. Hence you end up with "search" as your `id` when calling `GET` with the URL provided.

You could try the following:

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string id)
```

Then call it as follows:

```
GET /api/plans/search?id=<guid_string>&page=1`
```

`id` will then be set to a string that can be parsed as a guid.